# Node.js how to get HTML after site is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, browser

HTML I am getting using node.js is much different than HTML I can see in the browser (using google chrome inspect feature). I assume this is happening because when using browser I have to wait for some elements to load but I don't wait for them when creating a request. How can I request a fully loaded HTML? Is it possible without pretending to be a real user (puppeteer)?

For example, this is my attempt to get a video element from this link https://clips.twitch.tv/IronicPoisedTermite4Head
but video element is not present at all in the HTML I have fetched.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const jsdom = require("jsdom");

(async () => {
  let htmlDoc = await fetch("https://clips.twitch.tv/IronicPoisedTermite4Head")
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then((body) => body); //body is totally different than HTML in the browser
  try {
    const document = new jsdom.JSDOM().window.document;
    console.log(htmlDoc);
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Basically you can't. If the site runs JavaScript code which modifies the HTML, then you need it to run in a browser like environment to get the final product. Fetch will just grab whatever static content is at that location and return it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a browser loads a web page, it does an HTTP GET and gets back a static piece of HTML.  Let's call that the "original content".  It then parses that HTML and runs any `<script>` tags it finds in that HTML.  Those script tags may then modify the content you see.  In particular some sites make additional HTTP requests to retrieve additional content and then they insert that content into the page.  The produces what I will call the "full content".  Those scripts may even continue running over time to continue to update the content.

When you do a `fetch()` of some URL, that retrieves what was labeled above as the "original content".  That's all it does.  `fetch()` just does the initial HTTP GET for that URL.  It doesn't parse the resulting HTML and it doesn't run any of the `<script>` tags it could find in that HTML.  Thus, `fetch()` does not produce the "full content" as described above.  Sometimes, the "original content" is sufficient for your work and sometimes the "full content" is what you need - it really depends upon the specific web site.

To get the "full content", you have to feed the "original content" to a browser-like environment that can "run" it to let its scripts do their things, to provide a DOM environment for those scripts to run in so you can then query the resulting DOM to get the "full content".  puppeteer is one such tool for obtaining the "full content".  It actually uses the Chromium engine (same engine the Chrome browser uses) to literally "run" the web page and let its `<script>` tags do their thing and you can then obtain the "full content" from it after those scripts run.

`fetch()`, by itself, cannot get the "full content" because it doesn't parse or run the page's scripts and doesn't offer a DOM environment for them to run in either.  That's what a tool like puppeteer can do.

> How can I request a fully loaded HTML? Is it possible without pretending to be a real user (puppeteer)?

If the site builds its "full content" uses Javascript in `<script>` tags, then you have to use a tool like puppeteer to get the "full content".  It's not just a matter of waiting.  You need a tool that actually runs the scripts in the page.